# Lebesgue measure = 0 --> function is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Given a function $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Let $N := ${$x \in \mathbb R^n : f $ is not continuous in $x$ }.

If the Lebesgue measure of N is zero, why does follow from this that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: You need to show that the inverse image of a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Do you see why this is true when $N = \varnothing$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $f$ is measurable. You need to show that the pre-images of Borel subsets are Lebesgue measurable. In fact, it suffices to show that the pre-image of every open subset is measurable (prove it!).

You look at the restriction of $f$, that is, $g:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus N\to \mathbb{R}.$ Now, by the continuity of $g$, pre-image of every open subset is open in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus N.$

If $U$ is open subset of the real-line then $f^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(U)\cup A$ where $A$ is some subset of $N$ (and hence is measurable and has measure $0.$)

Since $g^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus N$ it should be equal to $V\cap N^c$ where $V$ is open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n.$ It is now clear that $f^{-1}(U)$ is Lebesgue measurable for every open subset $U.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be open.

$f^{-1}(G)=\{x\in{\mathbb{R}^{n}-N}:f(x)\in G\}\cup\{x\in N: f(x)\in G\}:=S\cup T$, we have $S=f|_{\mathbb{R}^{n}-N}^{-1}(G)$ and this is open in ${\mathbb{R}}^{n}-N$ and hence $S=({\mathbb{R}}^{n}-N)\cap U$ for some open $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $T$ is also a measure zero set, so their union is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_k(x)= f(\frac i {2^{k}})$ if $\frac {i-1} {2^{k}} \leq x <\frac i {2^{k}}, i \in \mathbb Z$. Then $f_k$ takes a constant value in each of the intervals $[\frac {i-1} {2^{k}} ,\frac i {2^{k}})$. Hence $f_k$ is Borel measurable. Also $f_k(x) \to f(x)$ whenever $x \notin N$. Hence $f$ is Lebesgue measurable.